# Quando eu devo usar um objeto string e uma string literal?

Tags: javascript, string, objetos

Lendo um artigo encontro o seguinte trecho:

> Você pode chamar qualquer um dos métodos do objeto string em uma
>   string literal - JavaScript automaticamente converte a string literal
>   para um objeto string temporário, chama o método, em seguida, descarta
>   o objeto string temporário. Você também pode usar a propriedade
>   String.length com uma string literal:

```
console.log("John's cat".length) 
// Irá exibir a quantidade de caracteres na string incluindo o espaço em branco. 
// Nesse caso, 10 caracteres.
```

Me corrijam se eu estiver errado, mas pelo que entendi quando eu defino uma `string literal` ele converte a mesma para um objeto `String` temporário, minha dúvida é a seguinte, existe diferença entre fazer:

```
var palavra = 'Palavra'; // String literal
var palavra = String('Palavra'); // String object
```

Quando devo usar uma `string literal` ou um `objeto String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O JavaScript não faz muita diferença entre um valor de string e um objeto de string. Ambos permitem que você use os mesmos métodos em seus conteúdos, de modo que, em geral, você não precisa criar um objeto de string toda vez que quiser atribuir um valor de string a uma variável. Uma operação de atribuição simples (`var palavra = 'Palavra';`) é tudo do que você precisa para criar um valor de string que se comporta, na superfície, de modo muito semelhante a um objeto de string completo.

A diferença aparece exatamente quando você deseja explorar o "lado objeto" de um objeto string genuíno.

Objetos strings definidos com o construtor `new String("valorString")` são objetos poderosos comparados com as variáveis simples, que recebem valores de strings. Você certamente não precisa criar esse tipo de objeto para cada string nos seus scripts, mas eles são muitos práticos se você descobrir que as strings nas variáveis estão erradas. Isso acontece ocasionalmente enquanto se tenta preservar informações de string como variáveis de script em outros frames ou janelas. Usando o construtor do objeto string, você pode ter relativa certeza de que o valor da string estará disponível no frame distante quando for necessário.

Outro subproduto dos verdadeiros objetos de string é que você pode posicionar propriedades e métodos de protótipo a todos os objetos de string no documento. Um protótipo é uma propriedade ou um método que se torna parte de cada novo objeto criado depois que os itens do protótipo são acrescentados. Para strings, como por exemplo, você pode querer definir um novo método para converter uma string em um novo tipo de tag de fonte HTML, ainda não definido pelo objeto string do JavaScript.

A seguir é mostrado como criar e usar esse tipo de protótipo.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>String Object Prototype</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.1">
function makeItHot() {
    return "<span style='color:red'>" + this.toString() + "</span>"
}
String.prototype.hot = makeItHot
</SCRIPT>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.1">
document.write("<H1>This site is on " + "FIRE".hot() + "!!</H1>")
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

O resultado é como segue:

```js
function makeItHot() {
 return "<span style='color:red'>" + this.toString() + "</span>"
}
String.prototype.hot = makeItHot


document.write("<H1>This site is on " + "FIRE".hot() + "!!</H1>")
```

Answer (score 4):

Quando você declara strings como no seu exemplo:

```
var palavra = 'Palavra';
var palavra = String('Palavra');
```

Não possui diferença alguma, as 2 formas estão declarando strings primitivas.

Acredito que o artigo de onde você leu estava falando da declaração com o uso da palavra chave `new` na criação da string, o que na verdade declara um objeto `String`:

```
var palavra = new String('Palavra');
```

Você não deve declarar objeto `String` a não ser que realmente precise. O javascript já faz essa conversão de forma automática, por isso é possível acessar métodos e propriedades de um objeto `String` a partir de uma string primitiva, como você mesmo cita.

Mesmo sendo quase a mesma coisa na prática, as 2 ainda possuem algumas diferenças, entre elas, a impressão do tipo:

```js
console.log(typeof "string primitiva") // string
console.log(typeof new String("objeto string")) // object
```

e o resultado de uma operação matemática em um `eval`:

```js
console.log(eval("1 + 1")) // 2
console.log(eval(new String("1 + 1"))) // 1 + 1
```

Mas ainda assim, tendo um objeto `String`, você consegue facilmente converte-lo de volta para uma string primitiva utilizando o método `valueOf`:

```js
console.log(typeof new String("string").valueOf()) // string
```

*Créditos a [documentação oficial do Mozilla sobre strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).*